# SP 2013 sync with AD not updating manager change

Tags: profile-sync, ad

When the manager on an existing employee is updated in AD, some are not syncing and others are.  I can't see anything different about the manager property for those employees that would cause an issue.

Comment: How did you configure UserProfileSync? Via AD-Import or ForefrontIdentityManager? The next steps in troubleshooting depend on that.

Comment: Its "SharePoint Profile Synchronization"